# Python, Unbound Local Error occurring despite initializing the local variable

Tags: python, runtime-error

I'm running into an unbound local error message that I am not understanding.  I am setting the default value of a variable to None (just so it is initialized) then in the next function, I run an if statement to check if it is still None, or if I have assigned it something else, and that is when I am getting the error.  Please see the code below.  Any help would be good.

```
from sys import stdout

restore_out = None

def toggle_out (toggle=1):
    if toggle == 0:
        if restore_out == None:
            restore_out = stdout
        stdout = None
    elif toggle == 1 and restore_out != None:
        stdout = restore_out
```

I'm using this to toggle standard output, so when I run a command with os.system('some command') that there is no output.

The code is supposed to call toggle_out(0) to turn it off, and toggle_out(1) to re-enable it.

Please let me know if anything comes to mind.

Comment: Your function tries to reassign `restore_out` (i.e. `restore_out = stdout`) but it doesn't declare `global restore_out`. So `restore_out` is treated as a variable local to the function, and at the point when the `if` and `elif` statements are executed,  it isn't initialised.

Comment: this is a very common error, if you just google it you will get many results from StackOverflow that discuss this error. The duplicate target was the top hit when I searched for "unboundlocal error python stackoverflow"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to a variable within a function that was defined outside of that function's scope. In your case, you are trying to assign a value to `stdout` and `restore_out` variables inside the function `toggle_out`, which are defined outside of the function's scope.

When you define a variable inside a function, Python assumes that you are creating a new variable that is local to that function. This means that if you try to access or modify a variable that was defined outside of the function's scope, Python will assume that you are referring to a different variable.

You can use the `global` keyword to explicitly tell Python that you want to use the variables that were defined outside of the function's scope.

```py
from sys import stdout

restore_out = None

def toggle_out (toggle=1):
    global stdout, restore_out
    if toggle == 0:
        if restore_out == None:
            restore_out = stdout
        stdout = None
    elif toggle == 1 and restore_out != None:
        stdout = restore_out
```